# Invoke Server Methods From Client Side Using jQuery AJAX in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have to call server side method update(input parameters) by using ajax call.when I am running the code my ajax is not loading.I want to update that data to Jquery Data table.please give me suggestions

$(document).on('click', '#btnsave', function () {

```
                        //have to get the emp_id
                        var id = $('#hdnid').val();
                        update(id);

                    });
```

function update(id) {

```
            var name = $('#txtempname').val();

            var sal = $('#txtsal').val();

            var Dept_Id = $('#ddllist').val();

            $.ajax({
                //var Data = "{ empname:" + name + "}";

                url: 'jdatatable.aspx/update',//my  .aspx page name 

                type: "POST",

                data: '{ id: ' + id + ',empname: "' + name + '", sal: ' +sal + ', Dept_Id: ' + Dept_Id + ' }',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                dataType: "json",

                "success": function (data) {

                    alert("successfully done");

                    table.ajax.reload();

                    $('#txtempname').val('');

                    $('#txtsal').val('');

                    $('#ddllist').val('');

                },
                "error": function (data, xhr, status) {
                    alert(status);
                }
            });
```

jdatatable.aspx.cs

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {




        }


    }
```

//mymethod
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]

[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, XmlSerializeString = false)]

```
    public void update(int id, string empname, int sal, int Dept_Id)
    {

        string s =    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconn"].ToString();
        List<UserDetails> li = new List<UserDetails>();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(s);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_update", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", id));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Emp_Name", empname));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Sal", sal));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Dept_Id", Dept_Id));
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: The AJAX seems fine so I would recommend to use Web Developer Tools (FireBug / Chrome Developer Tools) to examine if 
a) any error is shown when `#btnsave` is clicked (also make sure you are not having any typos in the selector names) 
b) what is being sent to the server and if there is any response returned.

Comment: I have done debugging with chrome developer tools....ajax call is not loading and the "data" in the ajax is not showing any data.I am trying to update my data table by giving input parameters.I have successfully done the same task by using web services.But from "aspx" page it is not working

Comment: I am getting the following error   [Unknown web method update.
Parameter name: methodName  ]

Comment: If you are not seeing any HTTP request being sent to the server there is something wrong with your AJAX call and not an the server side. Things to consider: rename your function `update()` to something more individual like `updateData()` to not interfere with other functions, make sure that the script handling the button press is able to access the function. Set a breakpoint inside your `update()` block to see the function is actually called.

Comment: my update(id) function is firing,inside that when pointer reaches to ajax it is going out from the loop and displaying internal server error....and my "update" method on server side is not calling

Comment: got the solution..... my method should be static

Comment: Good you found the solution. Please close this question, good luck with your first ASPX application :-)